# undefined value used in expression (could be an out of range array subscript )

Tags: javascript, after-effects

I am about to have an absolute god damn stroke trying to understand how to write an expression in After effects. It seems pretty much everything I do results in the error "undefined value used in expression (could be an out of range array subscript)" which as far as I understand is an error that means exactly nothing of substance.

I'm pretty sure I got a code exactly like this working a moment ago, but now I get the same error. What am I not understanding?

```
redx = thisComp.layer("layername").transform.xPosition.valueAtTime(time-1)
yellowx = thisLayer.transform.xPosition
if (redx < yellowx) {
    [redx]
}
```